# What to do with questions that had their content erased?

Tags: discussion, edits, vote-to-delete, rollbacks

From time to time, I run across questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18731763/what-does-the-following-code-output). When I do, I usually vote to close (as I did here), but actually that does not seem sufficient to me.

I thought about whether it made sense to rollback the last edit to at least restore the question that was asked? Or maybe just leave a comment noting that you can delete your own questions? Or maybe flag it as very low quality? Or maybe just do what I did and wait till the question is deleted some time in the future?

Since I ran across some of these already, there probably is some consensus on how to deal with these.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there was an answer, or any kind of solution, a rollback is necessary as the content is valuable for future users.

But since there is no answer, no hint as to what the solution is, I think the best think is to vote to delete if you have the privileges or flag for mod attention.  A custom flag is probably best explaining in detail why the post needs deleted.  A very low quality flag, while accurate in its vandalized state, likely will not be accurate in the future so would likely get dismissed.

(I still think you should rollback the post before it is deleted)

In either case, a comment to the OP that vandalizing there posts is not acceptable is also appropriate.

But don't forget to vote to close if the post deserves to be closed.  In fact, if the post has enough downvotes and gets closed, it might get [automatically deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006) during normal cleanup as a closed post with a negative score and no answers.

Comment: If there is any indication that it was a trivial error like a typo and no answer is pointing this out already, I think you should also vote for close with a custom reason.

Comment: @kapep Closing should always be the first part of an off-topic question, but I left the idea of closing out, partly because the OP mentioned that he did vote to close in the question and partly because closing might not always be appropriate when dealing with a vandalized post.  I will add a note though.

Comment: yep, just wanted to point it out because I think that question would have been closed regardless of the vandalism.

Answer (score 7):

If you see that a user removed the question after it has been solved, then you should rollback to the original content and you could also leave a comment explaining the matter.

If the user removes the content again, flag for moderator attention.